# Duplicating Code Versus Potentially Wasted Variables

Tags: performance, coding-style

For example:

```
//In this case, x is always declared but may not be used
int x = 5;
if(this()){
      if(x < y)
            doThis();
}
else if(that()){
      if (x < z)
            doSomethingElse();
}
else
      dontNeedX();
```

versus

```
//In this case, x is never declared unnecessarily but it is duplicated
if(this()){
      int x = 5;
      if(x < y)
            doThis();
}
else if(that()){
      int x = 5;
      if (x < z)
            doSomethingElse();
}
else
      dontNeedX();
```

Which is better from a performance standpoint versus a readability standpoint?

Comment: The compiler should be able to optimize away x in the first case. If it really makes a difference ... . If x is a more complicated object with side effects in its construction this may not be the case. But with integers the compiler is much to intelligent to allocate a variable with the value 5. Most likely it will hardcode the 5 in the check opcode if possible (x86). At best this is a micro-optimization at worst you are wasting your time thinking you are 'more clever' then the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt performance is an issue here. Arguably you have more overhead with the duplication, but unless x is some really large object, it shouldn't matter.
My question would be is 'x' logically the same entity in doThis and doSomethingElse?
If it's the same 'thing' (which could be the integer value x represents or some other object) then use #1, otherwise use #2.